# Are there any RPGs released based on the world of Bas-Lag?

Tags: game-recommendation, campaign-settings

[Bas-Lag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bas-Lag) is the great world of some novels from the British author China Miéville. Does anyone know any RPG based on this world?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Dragon Magazine issue #352](http://paizo.com/dragon/products/issues/2007/352) detailed Bas-Lag for D&D 3.5.

The RPG publisher Adamant Entertainment has had the license for **Tales of New Crobuzon** since 2008. [According to owner Gareth-Michael Skarka](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?408175-Tales-of-New-Crobuzon-anyone-know-how-its-progressing&p=13813784#post13813784), the book is due for release in fall of 2011, and [it will use a variant of Chaosium's Basic Roleplaying (BRP) system](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?408175-Tales-of-New-Crobuzon-anyone-know-how-its-progressing&p=13816453#post13816453).  No updates have been posted for years and the owner has been banned from the forum, however.  [Adamant's official website](http://www.adamantentertainment.com/submissions/) gives no release date for the game, but has an advertisement for hire for freelance artists interested in producing interior art for the book, indicating it is fairly well along the production process at this point and has yet to be dropped.

Comment: That's sad. It would make a great addition to any of the RPG engines out there. I'd pay to own a Savage Worlds Bas-Lag port.

Comment: D&D can be tuned to thaumaturgy, torque and crisis-energy? Great. An own game designed for this world would be better though. I should make Paizo happy and buy this copy of the magazine.

Comment: I've known for a while that Adamant had this licence, but it's been a long time with no news! Anyone hear any rumours??